# How to Parse and Append text to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 via a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Does anyone know of a way to append text to a stored procedure from within another stored procedure? I would like to do something like the following in SQL Server 2005:

```
    Declare str as Nvarchar(Max) = '' 
    set @spStr = dbo.spTest + 'Where testCol1 = ''Test'''
    exec(@spStr)
```

I understand this may open some discussion about SQL injection attacks.  I'm simply looking to see if syntax exsists to extend a stored procedure by passing it a where clause dynamically in the above manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options.

You can alter the actual SP using the metadata in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES (not really what I think you are wanting to be doing)

You can parameterize the SP - this should not be vulnerable to injection if the SP uses the variable directly and not to dynamically make SQL.

You might consider using a view or an inline or multi-step table-valued function instead, which can be used like a parameterized view (inline being more efficient) - `SELECT * FROM udf_Test WHERE TestCol1 = 'Test'`.

You can take the results of the SP and put them in a temporary table or table variable and query against that.

Comment: I like the last suggestion, which is the same as the answer below.

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #tmp;
CREATE TABLE #tmp (col1 varchar(10))
INSERT #tmp (col1)
EXEC spTest
declare @spstr as nvarchar(Max)
set @spStr = 'Select * from #tmp Where col1 = ''1'''
exec(@spStr)

Answer (score 3):

There is no syntax like this available in Sql Server any version. You've got a couple of options:

1. You could obviously modify the procedure to include a parameter that the procedure code itself would handle as a filter in the final statement(s) that returned the result set from the procedure call.  Though I'd advise against it, you could certainly have a parameter that was just a varchar/nvarchar data type which included the actual 'where' clause you want to add and have the procedure code append it to these final select statement(s) as well
2. Use the [insert/exec syntax](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) to populate a temp table with the results of the stored procedure execution and then simply run a filtered select against that temp table.

Comment: I like the second suggestion...Thanks!